# Netbeans: Override the base URL used when running a web project

Tags: netbeans, web

When I click "Run" in a Java based Netbeans Web project the project is deployed to my local JBoss instance and then the browser is opened pointing to JBoss' HTTP base URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/
```

How can I change Netbeans' configuration so that it will always open JBoss' HTTPS URL:

```
https://localhost:8443/MyApplication/
```

Netbeans only allows me to change the context path:

[image]

Comment: Along the same lines, I'd like to know how to set the hostname.  I don't want "localhost", I want the actual hostname of my development machine.

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

Go to Netbeans IDE tools > options > general > web browser > edit > arguments

on the text box put the preferred URL